# Changing column to just a regular column instead of foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have a specific situation where I have a column type in my DB where the column is currently of type int and it is a foreign key type that allows nulls...

My question is: is it possible to change now this column simply to a int type which isn't a foreign key without messing up the data in both tables, and leaving the values intact?

For example:

```
alter table xy
alter column ForeignKeyIdColumn int null
```

Would something like this work?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You can drop the foreign key constraint.  However, if it is a foreign key, it is generally better to have that explicitly declared.

Comment: what is actual datatype of column ? whats your rowcount ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would I do that without affecting the data in both tables? Can you show me in an example?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key is not a property of the columns of a table, it's a database object that defines the relationship between tables.

You can drop the foreign key constraint (though I wouldn't recommend it) using `ALTER TABLE` with `DROP CONSTRAINT`, but you have to know the name of the constraint to do it (this is why it's best practice to name everything in SQL SERVER):

```
ALTER TABLE xy
    DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint name here>;
```

However, as I wrote, **I wouldn't recommend dropping foreign key constraints.**
Foreign keys are the database way to enforce referential integrity - meaning that a value referenced by another table can't be changed or deleted without changing or deleting the referencing value as well.
Dropping foreign keys means your database will not be able to enforce referential integrity any more and that might lead to corrupt data.

For more information, read [Delete Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-foreign-key-relationships#TsqlProcedure)

Comment: Hey Zohar , thx for the quick reply... Is there any way to see the constraint name somewhere in the table ?

Comment: You can get all the information on the table using `sp_help`, like this: `exec sp_help tableName`

Comment: @User987 I would also consider rowcount of table, if u have millions of rows and you want to change datatype of existing column, will stretch your log file. `SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE ‘%CONSTRAINT’` to get list of constraints

Comment: If you are using SSMS you can simply look at the Keys.